# finding a function holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, derivatives

Using the Cauchy Riemann Equations, find a function $f$ holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}$ satisfying

$$\Re{\left(f(x+iy)\right)}=\sinh{(x^2-y^2)}\cos{(2xy)}$$

---

If we let $f(x+iy) = u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ where $x,y,u,v\in\mathbb{R}$ then we have that

$$u(x,y) = \sinh{(x^2-y^2)}\cos{(2xy)}$$

Then from the Cauchy Riemann equations we know that

$$v_y = u_x = 2x\cosh{(x^2-y^2)}\cos{(2xy)} - 2x\sinh{(x^2-y^2)}\sin{(2xy)}$$
Then we can integrate with respect to $y$ to find $v$:

$$v = 2x\int \Big[\cosh{(x^2-y^2)}\cos{(2xy)} - \sinh{(x^2-y^2)}\sin{(2xy)}\, \Big]{\rm d}y$$

However we can't integrate this easily as it is. What's the best way to approach this integral?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: notice that
$$
\Re f(x+iy)=\sinh{\Re(z^2)}\cos{\Im(z^2)}.
$$
This suggests finding first a function $g$ such that
$$
\Re g(x+iy)=\sinh{\Re(z)}\cos{\Im(z)}=\sinh x\cos y.
$$
Then
$$
\Re g(z^2)=\sinh{\Re(z)}\cos{\Im(z)}=\sinh (x^2-y^2)\cos (2xy)
$$
and so you can take $f(z)=g(z^2)$.